# POST Request Swift 3.0 Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to do a .POST request with Alamofire in Swift 3. I´ve written the following function

```
func postToken(Token: String) {
    let parameters : [String:Any] = ["api_key":"ivaomobileapp", "function":"login", "IVAOTOKEN=":"\(Token)"]
    Alamofire.request("URL", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let data = response.result.value{
                print(data)
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error as Any)
            break

        }
    }
}
```

But the code doesn´t work, it gives the following error:

```
Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))
```

This is the same request in CURL(UNIX)

```
curl https://whatever -X POST -F 'api_key=ivaomobileapp' -F 'function=Login' -F 'IVAOTOKEN=whatever'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: the server side response is irregular, your code is fine

Comment: The answer is an invalid JSON object.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I made it return JSON now, still same issue.

Comment: validate your json once,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik This is what I am returning now: {"msg":"user login successfully entered."}

Comment: your `print(data)` is `"msg":"user login successfully entered."}` thsi

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik But I still have the same issue, Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

Comment: use ` .responseString instead of .responseJSON` and try once

Comment: see this once also https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1281

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I fixed that problem. But now the parameters are not being correctly posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you handle the addition of the `IVAOTOKEN` parameter in the wrong way, causing issues, perhaps creating a malformed dictionary. Perhaps your parameters should look like the following:

```
let parameters : [String:Any] = [
      "api_key": "ivaomobileapp", 
      "function": "login", 
      "IVAOTOKEN": Token
]
```

Alamofire will add the quotes around the `Token` variable, as it is a String. The result should be that the following is sent to the server:

```
{
    "api_key": "ivaomobileapp", 
    "function": "login", 
    "IVAOTOKEN": "TOKENVALUE"
}
```

Comment: I have a problem sending the api_key parameter, in the CURL request it is as follows 'api_key=ivaomobileapp'. Should I put somewhere the = in the Alamofire. Sorry, I´ve never done POST Requests with Alamofire :(

Comment: Well, do you literally use the value `ivaomobileapp` for the `api_key` parameter? I would think a key would look actually look somewhat different. Maybe like some sort of random hash. Either way, the `=` sign should not be part of the parameter key. Alamofire will transform your parameters to valid JSON and as such will add the `=` sign between the key and the value.

Comment: I think you should make 100% sure you can use this value as API key, as it's highly unusual. Usually it's a random hash or some such. Especially if you compare it with API keys from Facebook, Twitter, Flickr, etc...

Comment: yeah completely sure, CURL works with that value. My Chinese partner made the API so maybe it´s a mistranslation between Mandarin and English.

Comment: Well, another thing that's different with your curl request, is that in your curl request you actually don't send JSON, but you use a form request. So you might want to change a different kind of request. Or transform your curl request to a JSON request, if your server supports this.

Comment: Perhaps try a form request like here, that should be mostly similar with the curl request you are using: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37178808/250164

Answer (score 0):

Response from a server isn't valid json try using `responseString`, `responseData` or `response` to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I tried changing to responseData, same issue.

Comment: my means the server side data is not valid JSON

Comment: What can I do to figure it out?